# How to add multiple fields in bootbox.prompt in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, bootbox

I want to add a project name and task name while clicking on a particular date in fullcalendar but I don't know how to use bootbox.prompt or bootbox.dialog with more than one fields so can you help me out?

```
  select: function (start, end, allDay) {
        debugger;

        bootbox.prompt("Add New Event", function (title) {
            debugger;
            if (title !== null) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,

                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay,
                        className: 'label-info'
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );

            }


      });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, we can use bootbox dialog for that

```
bootbox.dialog({
                    title: 'Add New Event',
                    message:  $('#form'),
                    show: false,
                }).on("shown.bs.modal", function (e) {
                    $('#form').show()

                }).on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    /**
                     * Bootbox will remove the modal (including the body which contains the login form)
                     * after hiding the modal
                     * Therefor, we need to backup the form
                     */
                    $('#form').hide().appendTo('body');
                })
        .modal('show');
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            }
```

### In html

```
<form id="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" style="display: none;">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Username</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>
```